# How to move ordered list items with a specific class to the top of the list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I move ordered list items with a specific class to the top of the list using jQuery?

For example, in the following html code:

```
<div id="notice">click here</div>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li class="top">Tea</li>
  <li class="top">Milk</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

I want to move the li itmes with the class "top" to the top of the list when I click "Click here".

```
<div id="notice">click here</div>
<ul>
  <li class="top">Tea</li>
  <li class="top">Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Optionally, it will be great if the items will be reverted back to their original positions when I click "Click here" again.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `var top = $('li.top'); top.detach().prependTo(top.parent())` should do the first part of the question.

Comment: @somethinghere The `detach()` is unnecessary. `prependTo()` will move an existing element. And there's a problem if there's more than one list with `.top` elements - they'll all move to the first matched element's parent.

Comment: @Jason. Thanks for your comment. I found the code at http://jsfiddle.net/BKg6z/. But it's about moving a div to its parent div. I will try to find out other solutions. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: @PaulRoub I know it's not the most robust way, that would be this more-verbose conker: `$('ul').each(function(){ $(this).children('.top').prependTo(this); });` I didn't know about the prepend, actually.

Comment: @somethinghere. Thanks for your comments. I don't know the code at http://jsfiddle.net/UpX3L/1742/ is correct grammatically but it does the first part. but when I add ".toggle()", it behaviors somewhat strange... http://jsfiddle.net/UpX3L/1743/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, you can use [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/).

I'd make use of [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to keep track of whether the list is sorted or not, but there are countless other ways of doing it (as I'm sure other answers will show).

[Here's a quick and dirty fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/bcbxftr6/1/). I've done away with the `id`, so you can support multiple lists on a page.

```
$('.notice').click(function(){
    var $ul = $(this).next('ul');
    if(!$ul.data('sorted')){
        $ul.data('original', $ul.html());
        $ul.data('sorted', true);
        $ul.prepend($ul.find('li.top'));
    } else {
        $ul.data('sorted', false);
        $ul.html($ul.data('original'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Why does everyone hate SO snippets? Good answer, though you also want to be able to revert the position, right? So maybe you could add some `data(index, $(this).index())` to be able to pop them back in the right place later.

Comment: @somethinghere I've just never found the button to create a snippet on SO (until I specifically went and looked just now :o)). The order should be OK with what I've posted. It grabs all the html within the `li` before it changes it. When the button is clicked again, it'll just replace all the html with what it grabbed before.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: lazy way, a move top for ahead, recover html for reverse.

```js
var oldHtml = $('ul').html();
var reversed = false;
$('#notice').click(function() {
  if (!reversed) {
    $.each($('li.top').get().reverse(), function(index, value) {
      $(value).insertBefore($('li')[0]);
    });
    reversed = true;
    return;
  }

  $('ul').html(oldHtml);
  reversed = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notice">click here</div>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li class="top">Tea</li>
  <li class="top">Milk</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.